# A bug that occurs during the synchronization test of a thread. Task cannot block the thread from running the following code

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Questions are as follows:
According to MSDN, when a thread acquires the lock, Monitor.Enter blocks other threads until the thread releases the lock. However, during the test, Monitor.Enter (object) can block other threads from running the following code block in the case of Thread, and it still runs the following code block without blocking in the case of Task.

```
class program
{
    static void Main(string[] ars)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <5; i++)
        {
            new Thread(Func){ IsBackground = true}.Start();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        //for(int i = 0;i< 5;i++)
        //{
        //  Task.Factory.StartNew(Func);
        //}
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    bool b = false;
    Monitor.Enter(locker, ref b);
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} 执行 b = {b}");
    }
}
```

The result：
Task：

[image: 图片说明]

Thread：

[image: 图片说明]

Result: As shown in the figure above, Task performs Monitor.Enter (locker) and executes the following code twice, while Thread executes it only once.

Reason: Personally suspect that the same thread can continue to run without releasing the lock?
Hope answer

Comment: The images are not shown, because: *403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access the URL on this server.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitor locks can be entered by the same thread repeatedly several times and will unlock it once the same number of releases are done. This is called reentrancy.

```
   private void MonitorSameThreadTest() {
    var obj = new object();

    lock (obj) {
        // Lock obtained. Must exit once to release.
        // No *other* thread can obtain a lock on obj
        // until this (outermost) "lock" completes.
        lock (obj) {
            // Same thread can actually enter again
            var lockTaken = false;
            try {
                Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockTaken);
                // Same thread can actually enter again
                // We've *re-entered* lock again.
            }
            finally {
                if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(obj);

                // Must exit twice to release.
            }
        }
        // Must exit once to release.
    }
    // the lock allowing other threads to obtain it.
}
```

Comment: Thank for you answer

Comment: @jzian I am glad I was able to help